# JavaFX 2: need to access underlying object from inside TableCell in TableView

Tags: tableview, javafx-2, tablecell

I have a TableView for which the base item is a custom class i.e. TableAdapter.
I am creating a ContextMenu in a custom cell factory for TableCells. In the EventHandler for the menu item, I need to access the underlying TableAdapter represented by the specific cell where the menu shows. If I call getItem() or getString() they both seems to return a String representation of the object, however, I need the object itself to access other fields. Thanks,

private final class cCustomTableCell extends TableCell 
{

```
    private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

    public cCustomTableCell(){
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Show in tree");
        menu.getItems().add(menuItem);

        menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
```

//              **THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO ACCESS THE UNDERLYING OBJECT**

```
            }
        });
        setContextMenu(menu);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the generic type. for example:

```
public class CheckBoxTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, Boolean> {}
```

The `getItem()` should return Boolean in that case